# How can I validate and handle errors in proper way?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Im totally noob with node. I want to validate if user exist in db and validate if passwords matches to each other. This is what I managed so far :

this is my router

```
const router = require('express').Router();
let User = require('../models/user.model');
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator')

router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
  User.find()
    .then(users => res.json(users))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

router.route('/add').post([
  check('username', "min 5").isLength({ min: 5 }).custom(value => {
    return User.findOne({
        where: {
            username: value
        }
    }).then(user => {
        if (user) {
          throw new Error('user exist');
        }
    });
  }),
  check('password', "cant be empty").isLength({ min: 8 }),
],(req, res) => {

  const errors = validationResult(req)
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    res.json("fields cant be empty")
  }

  if(req.body.password2 !== req.body.password) {
      res.json("passwords dont match")
  }

  const user = {
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password,
  }

  const newUser = new User(user);
  newUser.save()
    .then(() => res.json('User added!'))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

and this is my submit function on client side

```
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const user = {
      username: this.state.username,
      password: this.state.password,
      password2: this.state.password2
    }
    
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/users/add', user)
      .then(res => console.log(res.data))

    this.setState({
      username: ''
    })
  }
```

This works somehow but I'd like to do in proper way. I appreciate any tips how can I achieve this and how can I handle errors in proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mongoose buit-in validators for that.all schemaType have some in built validators.

```
const userSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
name:{
     type:String,
     required:[true,'Please provide user name'],
     minlength:5  
},
email:{
     type:String,
     required:[true,'Please provide email'],
     unique:true,
     validate:[validator.isEmail,'Please provide a valid email']
},
password:{
     type:String,
     required:[true,'Please provide password'],
     minlength:8, 
},
confirmPassword:{
     type:String,
     validate:{
           validator:function(el){
              return el===this.password;
             },
           message:'Passwords are not same!'
      }
}

});
```

Comment: Thank for your help. Please could you tell me how to get this message from required table and display on client site ?

Comment: when mongoose validators did not pass, the error (err) object will be grabbed by the .catch() in the promise. If you console log this error, you'll see in that object is our custom message and use err.message to get error message.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thanks again, I got it. What about confirmPassword validation ? is it ok to check if passwords match on the client side ? How can I use this validator method that you posted above ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about check function because I have never used express validator, but when it comes to cheacking the user exist you could use this simple funciton:

```js
User.exists({username: "username"});
```

This would return eitehr false or tru.

When it comes to validating the password. I think your code ok, but would add additonal module like bcrypt to hash the password when it is uploaded.